# Display a list of allowed entries in a different channel's field for a selected author

Tags: channel-entries, playa, filter, author

I get stucked.
I've to do this:
I've a channel "Projects" where a Super Author write a list of projects.
I've another channel "Articles" where Authors can write articles and make a unique relationship with a single entry in "Projects" channel.
But only Super Author can allow which Author can select that single project.
So in a field in "Articles" entry for that author, it should be listed only allowed "Projects" entries for that author.

EX: There is S_A (Super Author), A_1 (Author 1), A_2 (Author 2).
S_A make Prj_1, Prj_2, Prj_3 and assign that permissions:

```
Prj_1 -> A_1
Prj_2 -> A_1;A_2
Prj_3 -> A_2
```

A_1 when write an article in "Articles" channel can select from a dropdown only Prj_1 & Prj_2, and can't see Prj_3 in the list;

A_2A_1 when write an article in "Articles" channel can select from a dropdown only Prj_2 & Prj_3, and can't see Prj_1 in the list;

I've done this steps:
I've created 3 different channels:

```
- Authors (with plug-in Profile:Edit); 
- Project;
- Articles;
```

In Projects i've created this channel fields:
prj_author that is a Playa field to allow S_A to select allowed Authors.

In Articles i've created this channel fields:
art_projects that is a Playa field to show all the entries in the "Projects" channel, but here i can't filter entries for the selected author in prj_author playa field.

Please can somebody can help me?
I can offer a beer :D

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write a [custom fieldtype](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html) to achieve this - I can't think of any existing fieldtypes that could accomplish this for you.

So in your fieldtype, you'd query `exp_playa_relationships` for all `parent_entry_id`'s where where `child_entry_id` was equal to the `entry_id` associated with `ee()->session->userdata('member_id')`. (Not sure how *Profile:Edit* stores its Channel/Member relationships, but it's probably in a simple DB table.) Then, use that data to build a menu from there.

Very difficult to then pass this to a Playa field though - you'd be best off building your own dropdown menu.